# How to print member data from a struct using pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a pointer to a struct of type Map defined in an external header file:

```
typedef struct {
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
} Map;
```

The pointer is initialised as follows:

```
    struct Map *map_ptr;    
    map_ptr = create_map(*w_ptr, *h_ptr);
    // create_map returns Map*, w_ptr and h_ptr are pointers to height and width fields for a map/maze.
```

How do I go about printing the values of width and height stored within the Map structure which is created in create_map? create_map is held in an external file and the only variable it passes back to main is the pointer to the map.

The following gives an error when compiling ("error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type")

```
printf("Height = %d\n", map_ptr->height);
```

As far as I know, the pointer is valid as the code below prints a memory address:

```
printf("Pointer address for map = %p\n", map_ptr);
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it not do anything? Does it crash? What happens?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c).

Comment: C nit: `%p` args must be (cast to) ptr-to-void otherwise you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: See also this link, or the sample code below: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fnamspac.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just drop the `struct` keyword from:

```
struct Map *map_ptr;
```

to:

```
Map *map_ptr;
```

You have declared a nameless struct and typedef'ed it to `Map`. So when you declare `struct Map *map_ptr;`, compiler thinks this is *another struct* called `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You tripped over what is called *namespaces* in C. There are separate namespaces for

- typedef names, as you introduced with `typedef struct { ... } Map;`
- struct tags, as you introduced with `struct Map *map_ptr;`
- plus other namespaces for objects, macro names, ...

The same indentifier can be reused in different namespaces. I recommend to **never bother with typedefs for structs**. It only hides useful information, and all it does it saving you from writing `struct` every now and then. If something is a struct or pointer to a struct then *I want to know it so I know whether to use `->` or `.` to access the members*. Using typedefs defeats this by hiding useful information.

One way to fix your problem is to get rid of the typedef and only use a struct tag with

```
struct Map {
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
};
struct Map *map_ptr = ...;
```

Comment: Very, very good point - thank you.  I should emphasize that the C concept of "namespace" does *not* correspond to C++ "namespaces".  The two are different. Here's a link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fnamspac.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that might help clarify a few points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
} Map;


Map *
create_map ()
{
  printf ("Allocating %d bytes for map_ptr, and %d bytes for map data...\n",
    sizeof (Map), 100);
  Map *tmp = (Map *)malloc(sizeof (Map));
  tmp->squares = (char *)malloc (100);
  strcpy (tmp->squares, "Map data...");
  tmp->width = 50;
  tmp->height = 100;
  return tmp;
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Map *map_ptr = create_map();
  printf ("map_ptr->height= %d, width=%d, squares=%s\n",
    map_ptr->height, map_ptr->width, map_ptr->squares);
  free (map_ptr->squares);
  free (map_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Allocating 12 bytes for map_ptr, and 100 bytes for map data...
map_ptr->height= 100, width=50, squares=Map data...
```

An alternative approach would be to use "struct Map {...}" instead of the typedef:

EXAMPLE:

```
struct Map {
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
} Map;


struct Map *
create_map ()
{
...
  struct Map *tmp = (struct Map *)malloc(sizeof (struct Map));
  ...
}
  ...
  struct Map *map_ptr = create_map();
  printf ("map_ptr->height= %d, width=%d, squares=%s\n",
    map_ptr->height, map_ptr->width, map_ptr->squares);
  free (map_ptr->squares);
  free (map_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1：

```
struct Map *map_ptr;
```

to

```
Map *map_ptr;
```

Answer 2：

```
typedef struct {
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
} Map;
```

to

```
struct Map{
    char *squares; //!< A pointer to a block of memory to hold the map.
    int   width;   //!< The width of the map pointed to by squares.
    int   height;  //!< The height of the map pointed to by squares.
} ;
```

Reason ：

```
if typedef struct{...}  B；
```

so

```
B ＝＝ struct B{...}
```